# Replacing a user entered string with another

Tags: text-processing

So I am writing a program in bash involving a madlibs and I have to create a function that replaces the first occurence of a word for example. If the first word inputted was apple I can use this function to replace it with pear. How would I go about that in bash? (Very new to bash)

```
function replaceFirst(){
#Code to go here 

}
```

I saw some things about "sed" but as I said I am new so any help would be great!

Comment: Please provide example input and output texts (not just one keyword)

Comment: "_I saw some things about "sed"_" - what did you see and what did you try?

Answer (score 2):

To replace one word with another, there is no need to use external commands like `sed`. Bash itself can do the job.

```bash
function replace_first {
    local user_input="$1"
    local replace_with="$2"

    set -f -- $1
    local first_word="$1"

    echo "${user_input/#$first_word/$replace_with}"
}

# read user input
read -rp 'Enter some text: '

# sample usage
replace_first "$REPLY" Hello
```

`set` re-sets the positional parameters, so you can easily access the first word of the user's input. The `-f` option prevents filename expansion. Also note that `$1` is not quoted. In general, you should always quote your variables, but in this case word splitting is desired.

`${parameter/#pattern/string}` replaces only the first word of the string. This is in case the same word occurs elsewhere in the string.

Bash provides detailed information about [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Let's say the input text is `Hi there`. The output would look like this:

```bash
$ Enter some text: Hi there
Hello there
```